# Looking for example(s) of infinite abelian group $G$ , other than $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$, such that $\mathbb Z^+=\{o(g):g \in G\}$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, torsion-groups

Give example of an infinite abelian group $G$ (if exists) , other than $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ , such that $\mathbb Z^+=\{o(g):g \in G\}$ . Please help

Comment: Hint: consider a direct sum of cyclic groups of various orders.

Comment: What is ${\mathbb Z}^+$? Does it include infinity? If not, then $S^1$ is not an example, and if so then ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ is not an example.

Comment: @Derek Holt : I edited

Comment: $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \oplus A$ for any abelian group $A$.

Comment: @MooS: But taking $A:=\mathbb Z$ , what is the order of $(\mathbb Z , 1)$ in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Ah ok, so infinite order is excluded explicitly? Then take $A$ to be any finite abelian group.

Comment: You can still take the torsion subgroup of $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\oplus_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$